# How can I check if strings match?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Google Sheet document that I only have read access to.

It has a set of workers in it. One of the fields is for "job location", and another is for "house location". When these fields don't match, the worker is "remote".

I'm trying to add a calculated column to a data source in Google Data Studio, but I can't find any string function that checks for equivalence, and just going `J=K` doesn't work.

The [CASE operator](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724?hl=en) isn't able to compare columns either.

Is there a way to make a formula determine if two fields are equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, the feature was introduced in the [07 Jan 2021 update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#jan-7-2021); thus using the fields specified in the question (`job location` and `house location`), the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement below does the trick:

```
CASE
  WHEN NOT job location = house location THEN "remote"
  ELSE "not remote"
END
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d274eae4-c9f9-4e1c-b4f1-4a2115d049c7) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no direct solution in Data Studio to do this.

However, you can take one of two approaches:

1. Create a new Google Sheet. Use [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) to bring in entire dataset from the source Sheet and then add the comparison column in this worksheet. Use [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) to extend the formula all the way to the end. (e.g. `=ARRAYFORMULA(D:D=E:E)` - can be further polished) This Sheet can then work as your data source.
2. Create a [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started) to fetch data from the Sheet using the [Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets). Add the comparison as a column in Apps Script.